# Spark - Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Field

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I was getting below error for one of my spark job -

> Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   java.lang.reflect.Field

I realised that I had a class in one of the closures which was using keeping a java.lang.reflect.Field array in the memory. As java.lang.reflect.Field does not implement java.io.Serializable it cant be serialised by Spark and hence the error. How can I solve this error? It is not possible to not use Field.

1. Create a new instance of class in each executor so it is not serialized. I used https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/ which seemed to work for one object type but not for two.
2. Use Kryo serializer for my class which is using Field - Will this work? Does Kryo works with classes that don't implement java.io.Serializable.
3. Use broadcast variable - I am not sure about this. Does broadcast variable has to be serializable?

What are the other ways to solve this NotSerializableException when an object is truly cant be serialized for whatever reason.

Comment: could you be able to provide your code ?

Comment: Why would you want to serialize a Field in the first place? You can reconstruct it at the receiving end.

Comment: @EJP that's what I did to solve the problem but I had to refactor my code and change my design to remove Field from the classes. I wanted to find out if there are other ways to solve the problem when something truly cant be serialized and it cant be removed from you code also.

Comment: @SandeepSingh the code is irrelevant here. I just wanted to figure out ways to solve NotSerializableException when class cant be changed to Serializable

Comment: why not just declare those fields transient instead of removing them entirely?

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to not use Field?

Without understanding your code and what you are using those `Field` instances, we cannot possibly answer that.  (Obviously!)

But that's probably the wrong question.  The question you probably should ask is if it is possible to avoid serializing the `Field` objects.  The answer to that is Yes.

- You can mark the fields as `transient`.  That means that they won't be serialized.  If the `Field` references are just cached information, just look them up and cache them again .... if they are needed.
- You add custom serialization methods to the class the the `Field` fields belong to.  These could serialize the field names / signatures / whatever as string data, then attempt to resolve them again (via the Class API) when the data is deserialized.  In effect, you try to find *equivalent* `Field` objects in the context where you are deserializing.

---

I doubt that Kryo or broadcast variables (whatever they are).  A `Field` is fundamentally non-serializable since it depends on JVM state (class identity) that is not transportable.

A scheme that avoided serialization entirely might work, depending on how your application uses these objects.

---

> I was looking for inputs on solving the `NotSerializableException` when a class truly cant be serialized.

Well I take it that you are asking what to do if it is impossible to serialize the object by any means; e.g. custom serialization methods doesn't work, Kryo doesn't work, and nothing else works.  (I'm pretty sure that if neither custom serialization or Kryo works, then nothing else will work either.)

If none of the options for serialization of an object work, then you only have one thing you can do.  Don't serialize it.

And note that there are some classes where this is genuinely the case; e.g. Thread and many Swing and AWT classes are fundamentally non-serializable.

Comment: I was looking for inputs on solving the NotSerializableException when a class truly cant be serialized not how java.lang.reflect.Field can be removed from my program to make it work thats why I haven't pasted any code. I did the same thing where I stopped using Field and started using fieldName instead which is String. Later, Field was reconstructed using object.getClass().getDeclaredField(<<FieldName>>). I was caching it to make things faster when the actual operation runs as Field is more of a static data for me which can be cached ones and used multiple times.